# How to create content slider's arrows (React-Native)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

I need to create content slider [image: this]

I already created it using Horizontal ScrollView, but how to create logic for left and right arrows? Thank you.

Comment: ios, Android, JavaScript.... What language are you using to code?

Comment: I'm using javascript (React Native https://facebook.github.io/react-native/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pagination concept.
ScrollViews can be configured to allow paging through views using swiping gestures by using the pagingEnabled props. Swiping horizontally between views can also be implemented on Android using the ViewPagerAndroid component.
Reefer https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview.html